# Typescript - Promise returns to early

Tags: javascript, typescript, es6-promise

I'm given a code with 3 parts that must not be changed:

**1.** a call to *getData* function, and then prints the output.

```
getData().then(console.log);
```

**2.** The function signeture:

```
async getData(): Promise<string[]>
```

**3.** function *getDataFromUrl*

```
function getDataFromUrl(url: string, callback: any) {
   fetch(URL)
   .then((content: any) => content.json())
   .then((data) => callback(data));
}
```

This is my implementation for  getData function:

```
async getData(): Promise<string[]> {  
  return await new Promise<any>(function(resolve, reject) {
    resolve(getDataFromUrl(myUrl, ((data: string[]): string[]=> { 
      return data
    })))
  }); 
}
```

The problem is that the code after *fetch*, runs after

> getData().then(console.log);

so *console.log* prints: *undefined*

What do I need to change in the getData function?

Thanks

Comment: That's a horrible task. You absolutely *should* change `getDataFromUrl` to return a promise instead of accepting a callback.

Comment: The promise resolves too early because you call `resolve()` too early. Call `resolve()` from the callback you pass to `getDataFromUrl()`.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of resolving the `getDataFromUrl` function, you should resolve the value that the callback function exposes.

```
getData(): Promise<string[]> {  
  return new Promise<string[]>(function(resolve, reject) {
    getDataFromUrl(myUrl, (data: string[]): string[] => { 
      resolve(data)
    })
  }); 
}
```

It's unfortunate you can't change anything about the other functions, because returning the promise created by `fetch` in your `getDataFromUrl` function, would make the code *way* better, as Quentin demonstrates.

Answer (score 1):

`getDataFromUrl` doesn't have a return value, so it returns `undefined`.

So you pass `undefined` to `resolve` (which resolves your other promise) and then, **later** the promise created **by** `getDataFromUrl` (or rather `fetch`) resolves.

---

- Don't create bonus promises
- Don't mix callbacks and promises

---

Just return the promise from `fetch`.

```
function getDataFromUrl(url: string, callback: any) {
   return fetch(URL)
   .then((content: any) => content.json());
}
```

And use that promise instead of creating a new one in `getData` (which doesn't need to use `await` because that will just resolve the promise which will immediately get wrapped in a new promise by `async`.

```
getData(): Promise<string[]> {  
    return getDataFromUrl(myUrl);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```js
function getDataFromUrl(url, f) {
  // call fetch (returns promise) but we can use then as well.
  // note our callback: f where we pass the data to the callback.
  fetch(url).then((content) => content.json()).then(data => f(data));
}

// edit: note we don't need this be async anymore...
async function getData() {
  // create a promise...
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    // we call with callback arrow and resolve data here
    getDataFromUrl('https://randomuser.me/api/', (data) => resolve(data));
  })
}

// we print the data once the getData is done fetching
// you can also use reject to handle anything that goes wrong in above.
getData().then(data => console.log(data));
```

Resources used:

- Fetch API
- Async, Await, and Promise
- Callback